# Google Plus Crawler

Tags: google-plus, web-crawler

I am working with a social media analysis and I'm collecting datasets for research. I have been searching on the web about any way to make a Google plus crawler. I had great experience with Twitter Streaming API, and even Facebook Graph API, but, I did not find anything on Google+ documentation that can help me.

Then, my question is if does anyone know about the possibility to make a Google plus crawler to gather information of public posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear exactly what you're looking to crawl on Google+, but it sounds like you want the [Google+ API for the web](https://developers.google.com/+/web/). In particular, you'll probably want to use the [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get), [activities.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search), [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list), and/or [comments.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/comments/list) HTTP API instructions.

Be aware, however, that this will only return public comments that were not shared to a community, even if that community is a public community.

Comment: That's sound partly what I'm looking for. I would like to crawl posts related to a given query. Something like the facebook Graph API, for example: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=flappy+bird&access_token=<access_token>. Public posts and public comments would be enough for me. Do you have any ideia?

Comment: You'll probably want [activities.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) than.